# Search first occurrence and print until next delimiter, but match whole word only

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with multiple lines of text similar to:

```
foo
1
2
3
bar
fool
1
2
3
bar
food
1
2
3
bar
```

So far the following gives me a closer answer:

```
sed -n '/foo/,/bar/ p' file.txt | sed -e '$d'
```

...but it fails by introducing duplicates if it encounters words like "food" or "fool". I want to make the code above do a whole word match only (i.e. grep -w), but inserting the \b switch doesn't seem to work:

```
sed -n '/foo/\b,/bar/ p' file.txt | sed -e '$d'
```

I would like to print anything after "foo" (including the first foo) up until "bar", but matching only "foo", and not "foo1".

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Regex tokens `^` and `$` to indicate the start and end of a line respectively:

```
sed -n '/^foo$/,/^bar$/ p' file.txt
```

Comment: ...but is it possible to expand this to deal with non-word constituent characters preceding or following like "Name=foo, " and count as a positive match? @heemayl

Comment: @supertonic09 yes, possible..check if `sed -n '/^[^[:alpha:]]*foo[^[:alpha:]]*/,/^[^[:alpha:]]*bar[^[:alpha:]]*/ p' file.txt` is working for you..

Comment: I ended up taking a different approach, and decided to split the logic into two parts like this:

`foo_match=$(grep -m 1 -w foo file.txt);`
`sed -n "/$foo_match/,/bar/ p" file.txt | sed -e '$d'`

But off course, the above implementation works for me @heemayl, because I'm expecting the final application to contain a more complex string than just `foo`, making it unique when passed on to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/\<foo\>/,/\<bar\>/ p' file.txt
```

Or may be this if foo and bar have to be first word of any line.

```
sed -n '/^\<foo\>/,/^\<bar\>/ p' file
```